# How many solutions for the equation $t_1+t_2+t_3+t_4=6$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many solutions are there to the equation $t_1+t_2+t_3+t_4=6$ if $t_i\in \{-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ for all $i=1,2,3,4$?

I know how to answer this problem without the set of numbers $t_i$. But when I should keep the set $t_i$ in mind, I don't really know how to solve it. I know the answer might be smaller but again, I have no clue.

My idea is to use the formula: 
$C(n+r-1,r)$ and if I ignore the set, then there would be
$C(4+6-1,6)=C(9,6)=84$ ways but I have to use the set, any help?

Comment: Same question in essence as [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283285/how-many-solutions-are-there-to-the-equation-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-4-x-5-21).

Comment: Well, if you define $s_i=t_i+1$ then the sum of the $s_i's $ is $10$.  and  $s_i≥0$.  The upper bound is irrelevant is you couldn't have $s_i>10$ anyway.

Comment: So I get 286 possible ways to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem can be rephrased as:

How many solutions are there for $s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4=10$ if $s_i\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$?

Here we applied $s_i=t_i+1$.

Fortunately the demands that $s_i\geq0$ for $i=1,2,3,4$ together with $s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4=10$ allready force the $s_i$ not to exceed $10$, so another rephrase is possible:

How many solution are there for $s_1+s_2+s_3+s_4=10$ if the $s_i$ are nonnegative integers?

To solve that you can use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), leading to $$\binom{10+4-1}{4-1}$$ possibilities.

Comment: Ahhh I actually get the same answer as you! Very nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can define $u_i=t_i+1$ and now you are looking for the ways to solve $u_1+u_2+u_3+u_4=10$ with all the $u_i$ nonnegative.  The maximum is not a problem here as no solution has a $u_i \gt 10$ so use your usual stars and bars.

Comment: So I get 286 possible ways to solve it.